# What are the good references on tame hereditary algebras?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, representation-theory

I have Thomas Brustle's [Typical Examples of Tame Algebras](http://cs-linux.ubishops.ca/~bruestle/Publications/typical-examples.pdf), but I still do not have a systemic understanding of what tubes are and what regular roots of a tame hereditary algebra are. I'm also looking for the concept of defect.

Please give me some references on these things. One talk note or something similar is enough. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

There is a series of 3 books written by Assem, Simsom and Skowronski about the representation theory of finite dimensional algebras.
In the second book tame algebras are considered. This is by far the most comprehensive book about tame hereditary algebras.
Other representation theory books also treat tame hereditary algebras, examples:

-book by Gabriel Roiter

-book by ringel

-book by Barot, at least for the Kroenecker case in much detail.